# What is the generated grammar for this language?

Tags: complexity-theory

I want to construct a regular grammar that generates words that contain both "ab" and "bc" as subwords with the alphabet of the terminal symbols {a,b,c}

My solution so far is

**G=(Vn={S,X,Y},Vt={a,b,c},S,F={ S-> aS | bS | cS | abX | cbX, X-> aX | bX | cX | ε})**

Comment: What ls $\lambda$ supposed to be?

Comment: epsilon (empty word) .. I'll change it to ε

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution so far is incorrect. According to your solution, we have the derivation

S -> abX -> ab

which does not contain bc as a substring.

Your solution also has a non-terminal Y, but does not appear in any production rules.

A correct grammar follows, with start symbol $S$:

$S \to aS$
$S \to bS$
$S \to cS$
$S \to abcA$
$S \to abX$
$S \to bcY$

$A \to aA$
$A \to bA$
$A \to cA$
$A \to \epsilon$

$X \to aX$
$X \to bX$
$X \to cX$
$X \to bcA$

$Y \to aY$
$Y \to bY$
$Y \to cY$
$Y \to abA$

Comment: can we do it like this? {S->abS|bcS|Sab|Sbc|aSb|bSc|aS|bS|cS|Sa|Sb|Sc|ϵ}

Comment: @Johny that's not a regular grammar. And even if it were, it's still wrong. We would have $S \to \epsilon$, but $\epsilon$ does not have $ab$ as a substring.

Comment: that's right ... thank you 4 the information.